# Oracle try second condition only if first one gave nothing in join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm looking in Oracle for a way to do something like *if first condition has no match, do the second one*. Let's get to an example.

I have this JOIN in a query :

```
SELECT A.COL1, A.COL2, B.COL1, B.COL2 
FROM A
FULL JOIN (SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM B)
ON B.COL1 = A.COL1
       OR B.COL2 = A.COL2
```

And you see, with this OR condition I can have two created joins for the same `B` object. And I don't want that. What I would like is something like :

- if no result with *B.COL1 = A.COL1*
- then let's try a join with *B.COL2 = A.COL2*

Comment: `ON (B.COL1 = A.COL1) OR (B.COL1 <> A.COL1 and B.COL2 = A.COL2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the negation of the condition `B.COL1 = A.COL1` in the second filter. Naively, this is `B.COL1 <> A.COL1` but this does not handle `NULL` values so you need to use `B.COL1 <> A.COL1 OR B.COL1 IS NULL OR A.COL1 IS NULL` like this:

```
SELECT A.COL1, A.COL2, B.COL1, B.COL2 
FROM   A
       FULL JOIN (SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM B)
       ON (  B.COL1 = A.COL1
          OR ( ( B.COL1 <> A.COL1 OR B.COL1 IS NULL OR A.COL1 IS NULL )
               AND B.COL2 = A.COL2
             )
          )
```

Comment: Well thought, I assumed <> would handle NULL values

Comment: A boolean expression can have three values - `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `NULL` (an unknown value). `Value = NULL` outputs `NULL` and `Value <> NULL` outputs `NULL` which in both cases is not `TRUE` so the filter will never match those rows and you need to handle the `NULL` case specially.

Answer (score 1):

If `B.COL1 = A.COL1` then return row. Or, if `B.COL1 <> A.COL1` but `B.COL2 = A.COL2` also return row.

```
SELECT A.COL1, A.COL2, B.COL1, B.COL2 
FROM A
FULL JOIN (SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM B) B
   ON (B.COL1 = A.COL1)
   OR (B.COL1 <> A.COL1 and B.COL2 = A.COL2)
```