# PL_SQL hard for me join - dinamic ID-s in second table

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi_Guys! I tryed to resolve this but i have no idea how to. I have two tables, lets call TABLE_S and TABLE_G. In TABLE_S I have an ID and in TABLE_G i have two ID, ID1, and ID2.

```
TABLE_S     ID
TABLE_G     ID1    ID2
```

I want a left join, if theres no result for TABLE_G_ID1 then left join TABLE_G_ID2

something like this:

```
Select * from TABLE_S
       left join TABLE_G on TABLE_S.ID = TABLE_G.ID1 --if no result then:
                         on TABLE_S.ID = TABLE_G.ID2
```

I tryed this:
[Oracle try second condition only if first one gave nothing in join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48539731/oracle-try-second-condition-only-if-first-one-gave-nothing-in-join)

But doest work for me, and there is full join, not LEFT join

Appreciate your suggestion!!

Comment: Please edit your question and share some simple data and the expected output

Comment: Simple data is there: Select * from TABLE_S
       left join TABLE_G on TABLE_S.ID = TABLE_G.ID1 --if no result then:
                         on TABLE_S.ID = TABLE_G.ID2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AND` and `OR`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE_S s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_G g
       ON (  s.ID = g.ID1
          OR (
                 (s.ID <> g.ID1 OR s.ID IS NULL OR g.ID1 IS NULL)
             AND s.ID = g.ID2
             )
          );
```

*(Which is exactly the same logic as the question you link.)*

or use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE_S s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_G g
       ON s.ID = CASE s.ID WHEN g.ID1 THEN g.ID1 ELSE g.ID2 END;
```

*(Which is shorter to type but you may find that the SQL engine has difficulty using indexes on the columns due to them being inside the `CASE` expression.)*

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, unfortunately there is something wrong with the query. If I join only one ID, it takes a few seconds to run down, but if I use AND - OR, or CASE expression, still running after three hours. It seems as, it repeating itself endlessly, looping on something.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you are expecting, but one of the options is to do the join using IN() :

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e   D a t a:
    tbl_s (ID) AS 
        ( Select 1 From Dual Union All
          Select 2 From Dual Union All
          Select 3 From Dual Union All
          Select null From Dual Union All
          Select 5 From Dual Union All
          Select 6 From Dual Union All
          Select 7 From Dual 
        ),
    tbl_g (ID1, ID2) AS 
        ( Select 1,    101 From Dual Union All
          Select 9,      2 From Dual Union All
          Select 3,   Null From Dual Union All
          Select Null,   4 From Dual Union All
          Select 5,      5 From Dual Union All
          Select 8,    108 From Dual Union All
          Select 102,    7 From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--    M a i n   S Q L
Select    ts.ID, tg.ID1, tg.ID2,
          Case  When   ts.ID = tg.ID1 And ts.ID = tg.ID2  Then 'ID equals both ID1 And ID2'
                When   ts.ID = tg.ID2                     Then 'ID equals ID2'
                When   ts.ID = tg.ID1                     Then 'ID equals ID1'
          Else  'No Matching IDs'
          End "NOTES"
From      tbl_s ts
Left Join tbl_g tg ON(ts.ID In(tg.ID1, tg.ID2))
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
        ID        ID1        ID2 NOTES                     
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------------
         1          1        101 ID equals ID1             
         2          9          2 ID equals ID2             
         3          3            ID equals ID1             
                                 No Matching IDs           
         5          5          5 ID equals both ID1 And ID2
         6                       No Matching IDs           
         7        102          7 ID equals ID2                */
```

... in Left Join clause you can do whatever you want with null values in any of IDs in order to force the match if you want using Nvl() or COALESCE() functions. You could/should do it in Case expression too if you need to explain that forced match.

```sql
-- something like ...
Left Join tbl_g tg ON(Nvl(ts.ID, 99) In(Nvl(tg.ID1, 99), Nvl(tg.ID2, 88)))
```

Oracle comparison of Null is always false, you should test it with Is Null instead.

```sql
Select Case When Null = Null Then 'NULL' Else 'NO_MATCH' End From Dual
-- Above query results as NO_MATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not ideal, but I have had the same performance issues you are facing where the optimizer just gets flummoxed by an "OR" condition in the join. Where it just throws up it's hands and does a product join. Maybe if you are savvy with hints there is something to be done there. Making sure the statistics are fresh for all the ids also couldn't hurt.

If you find it's necessary you can try a sequence of LEFT JOINs and coalesce. It's ugly, but maybe the optimizer will have an easier time with two straightforward joins than one complex.

```
SELECT s.*,
       coalesce(g1.some_field_1, g2.some_field_1) as some_field_1,
       coalesce(g1.some_field_2, g2.some_field_2) as some_field_2,
       -- ...
       coalesce(g1.some_field_n, g2.some_field_n) as some_field_n
  FROM TABLE_S s
  LEFT 
  JOIN TABLE_G g1
    ON s.id = g1.id1
  LEFT
  JOIN TABLE_G g2
    ON s.id = g2.id2
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution for me is UNPIVOT.

```
with TABLE_G_For_join as(
   select * from TABLE_S
   unpivot (ids
       for ids_to_join in
                  (TABLE_G.ID1,
                   TABLE_G.ID2)))

select * from TABLE_S left join  TABLE_G_For_join on TABLE_G.ID1 = TABLE_S_For_join_ids
```

or something like this, but it works. Thanks to all!